# Which storage levels are cleared by PySpark's `clearCahce()`?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Judging by [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Catalog.clearCache.html), it seems like `spark.sql.Catalog.clearCache()` only clears dataframes that are persisted in memory.

If I were to persist a table in disk (`df.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY))`), would `cearCache()` unpersist it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spark, [cache](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache.html) is one of the options for data [persistence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.persist.html). `clearCache()` will not unpersist the data in your example, use `unpersist()`. It will marks the DataFrame as non-persistent, and remove all blocks for it from memory and disk.